# Humanoid mesh breaks when subdivided

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I've made a humanoid mesh, but it breaks around the chest and neck area when I subdivide as shown in the pics.

[Mesh after subdividing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caJ2a.png)

[image]

[image: Before subdividing]

So i cleaned up the mesh the best i could but its still not working out. What am I missing?

[image: Mesh after clean up]

Comment: Okay so I posted 2 pics, one showing the mesh before subdivision, but for some reason it didn't show. But i tried to remove all the triangles  and faces that intersect each other. So i don't think its that.

Comment: did you made with mirror modifier

Comment: @ateks yes i did

Comment: You probably don't have enough reputation to post more images you'll be able to when you have a higher score.,I've added it for you for now. Your mesh seems to have some topology issues, I see some ngons around the neck area. I also see some and weird artifacts in the chest. There may be overlapping or duplicate geometry. Cleanup your mesh and check your normals. Otherwise post more information, it is impossible to diagnose from the screenshots alone.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks a whole lot for that! I'm new to 3D modelling and kinda just using the internet to navigate my way through it. SO could you tell me what sort of information i could post for a more thorough diagnostic?

Comment: If you can provide us with your blend file that would be the best way to see what is wrong

Comment: How do I do that? As far as I can see theres no option for file attachments above.